# jquery: mudar o estilo de uma div dependendo do texto/numero que está nela

Tags: jquery

Amigos, tenho uma lista de items cuja cada item tem uma `div` que expressa dias restantes com uma função de contagem regressiva automática de data. Exemplo:

```
<ul class="items">
    <li class="item a"><div class="contagem-a">3 dias restantes</div></li>
    <li class="item b"><div class="contagem-b">8 dias restantes</div></li>
    <li class="item c"><div class="contagem-c">2 dias restantes</div></li>
    <li class="item d"><div class="contagem-d">6 dias restantes</div></li>
    <li class="item e"><div class="contagem-e">4 dias restantes</div></li>
</ul>
```

Quero que o fundo das divs tenham uma cor de acordo com a quantidade de dias que sobram. Exemplo: 1-2 dias > fundo vermelho. 3-4 dias > fundo amarelo. 5-6 dia > fundo verde. Por ser uma grande quantidade de itens e o tempo se alterar automaticamente, preciso que isso seja automatizado.

Para isso, imagino que precisa-se de uma função que identifique a ordem alfanumérica e consiga dar acesso á números seletos partir daí...

Alguém tem alguma ideia??

Comment: Ao invés do JQuery, não considerou resolver  isso apenas com CSS?

Comment: @LeandroAngelo eu não sei como fazer com CSS. como seria?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu criei uma função que irá receber um número e retornar o nome da classe referente a este.

Além disso, como os números são dinâmicos juntamente com todo o restante de sua string, fiz uma instrução que "filtra" apenas os números da string.

```js
(function() {
  const items = document.querySelectorAll('.items .item div');

  for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    const text = items[i].textContent; //Obtendo o conteúdo texto do elemento div que contém os contadores
    const number = parseInt(text.replace(/\D/g, "")); // Obtendo somente os números (dias) da string
    const bgClass = getClassBG(number);

    items[i].classList.add(bgClass); // Adicionando a classe ao elemento div
  }

  /* Obter a classe através do número */
  function getClassBG(number) {
    let bgClass = 'info';
    if (number >= 5) {
      bgClass = 'success';
    } else if (number >= 3) {
      bgClass = 'warning';
    } else {
      bgClass = 'danger';
    }

    return 'bg-' + bgClass;
  }
})();
```

```css
.bg-success {
  background-color: green;
}

.bg-info {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.bg-warning {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.bg-danger {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="items">
  <li class="item a">
    <div class="contagem-a">3 dias restantes</div>
  </li>
  <li class="item b">
    <div class="contagem-b">8 dias restantes</div>
  </li>
  <li class="item c">
    <div class="contagem-c">2 dias restantes</div>
  </li>
  <li class="item d">
    <div class="contagem-d">6 dias restantes</div>
  </li>
  <li class="item e">
    <div class="contagem-e">4 dias restantes</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Serviu perfeitamente! Muito obrigado!!!

Answer (score 1):

Eu usaria um identificador tipo data em cada div, para eu saber qual é qual ex:
data-id="2" data-cor="amarelo"

No jquery eu usaria o $(this).attr("data-id") para capturar o valor e qual objeto quero mudar a cor.